# Entity Framework - Mapping return from stored procedure which returns different set of output

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns data in this format

```
IF @Count = 0 
    SELECT 0
ELSE IF @COUNT = 1 
    SELECT 1
ELSE 
    SELECT 'Col_1', 'Col_2', 'Col_3' 
    FROM [TABLE_NAME] 
    WHERE [CONDITION]
```

When trying to map the result in Entity Framework for this 'Function Import', if I set the return as complex type consisting of 'Col_1', 'Col_2', 'Col_3', it works just fine when @Count is greater than 1. For @Count 0 or 1, I get an error about missing columns.

If I set the return as Integer, it works for @count 0 and 1 but not @Count > 1

I tried to make the columns in my complex type 'nullable' and also added a blank column set as integer but no success.

Is my only choice here to modify the SP to always return a single set of result? Or call the stored procedure the old fashioned ADO.NET way?

Comment: That's one of the most compelling reasons for **not** doing this - a stored procedure should ideally **always** return the same "shape" of data, e.g. same number and types of columns

Comment: I'm curious. If you ran `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name = '...'` and sometimes you got 10 person records and other times you got a single digit `1` would you, an intelligent human, be confused? Now imagine how confused EF must be, to always expect something it can turn into a Person entity..

Comment: I think that a good way to see how bad the logic is here is to consider what you would name a sproc like that so that someone with no previous experience with it could easily understand its purpose. A name like `GetThingsByName` makes it perfectly clear what a procedure/function does. What would you call this sproc? There is no simple name that clearly indicates its purpose so it is a bad sproc.

Comment: The idea was to return 0 if no match was found for the executing condition, 1 for exact match and the entire result set if more than 1 match exists. Our DBs felt this was the best way but it doesn't play well with the implementation code. 

I'll try to have this stored proc updated

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You've told EF that this procedure returns a resultset looking like X, and then in some cases that just isn't true.

I cannot see any compelling reason at all to write a sproc that does this; raise an error if you don't want to return an X

If you want to handle this complex/convoluted logic then EF is not the tool

Even if you, in cases where you want to return 0 or 1, returned a result set where one of the type compatible columns was set to that (eg if you're returning 10 Person rows a lot of the time but in these cases you return a single Person row that is all null apart from the Age being 0 or 1) you're then still going to have to know and cope with that crazy logic in the client side. The new developer that takes over your code will be sitting there scratching their head and going "something is wrong with EF; I write `context.Person.Where(p => p.Name = "kazinsky")` and I just get a single person back with an Age of 1, but I can see in the DB it's full of data and it's age 23, wtf"

> Is my only choice here to modify the SP to always return a single set of result? Or call the stored procedure the old fashioned ADO.NET way?

If I caught that kind of code in a project I was maintaining, I'd rip it all out- it's a terrible idea through and through. Your only logical choice here is to change the sproc. Anything else is just perpetuating a problematic design. Easiest way is to change the sproc so it raises an error "Input parameters matched 0 records"/"Input parameters matched 1 records; this sproc can only be called with parameters that match 2 or more because..."

Be kind to the person who will one day sit in your chair :)